# Как разделить дату и время в комментариях Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, datetime

То, как оперировать с датой и временем поста — более-менее понятно из конструкции в `template-tags.php`. Но как сделать то же самое с датой/временем в том или ином комментарии, я не нашёл. Предполагаю, что нужно злонамеренно выкрасть соответствующую конструкцию из какого-то файла ядра WP и модифицировать её для размещения в том же `template-tags.php`. Но это лишь догадка неофита.

Сейчас в html у меня «стандартный» код:

```
<time datetime="2022-10-19T21:27:52+03:00">
  19/X-22 21:27
</time>
```

Вместо него, хотелось бы видеть что-то вроде этого:

```
<time datetime="2022-10-19T21:27:52+03:00">
  <span class="crazydate">19/X-22</span>
  <span class="crazytime">21:27</span>
</time>
```

Как это сделать? Спасибо!